# Conic sections in addition and multiplication graphs of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: geometry, number-theory, conic-sections, visualization

Compare two kinds of addition and multiplication graphs of the cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$:

1. group tables (with colored circles on a rectangular grid)
2. line graphs (with straight lines connecting points on a circle)

In any case one observes "implicit" lines, circles, ellipses and hyperbolas, especially as contour lines in the group tables and as envelopes in the line graphs.

---

### Lines

- in addition group tables both for $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $n=20$:

[image][image]

---

### Circles

- in multiplication group tables for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $n=20$:

[image]

- in the addition line graphs for  $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $n=20$:

[image]

---

### Ellipses

- in the addition and multiplication line graphs for  $\mathbb{Z}$ (for addition by $20$, $50$ and $100$ and multiplication by $5$, $10$ and $50$):

[image]

[image]

---

### *Interlude: Cardioids, nephroids, etc.*

You may wish to compare these graphs to the apparent cardioids, nephroids, etc. in the multiplication line graphs for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $n = 100$, multiplication by $2,3,4$:

[image]

---

### Hyperbolas

- in the multiplication group tables for $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $n=100$:

[image]

- surprisingly one can discover hyperbolas even in multiplication line graphs for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, for example for multiplication by $85$ in $\mathbb{Z}/256\mathbb{Z}$:

[image]

---

My questions are:

> - By which general argument can be seen that one must not expect to "see" parabolas (the missing conic section) in any of these graphs?
> - How to prove that the envelopes in the line graphs really are circles resp. ellipses?
> - How to prove that the observed hyperbola-like contour lines in the multipication group tables really are hyperbola?